# CSS styling :before position? Extra space

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Fiddle here:  https://jsfiddle.net/sgbotsford/d52zyp0t/72/

Where does the extra first line indent come from in the `<li>` using => :before content?

[image: simple case to illustrate extra space after pseudo-element.]

Here's the problem.  Circumstances beyond my control put paragraph tags inside list elements.  When I use a :before, with a negative left, it works -- it sits out in the margin just like I want.  But the text-indent is increased where I've used the :before.  Where does this extra indent come from?

The desired behaviour is to have paragraphs and list items to be styled identically, except for the => floating off the left margin.

I'm sure I can eventually experiment enough to hack a solution, but right now I am trying to understand this behaviour in terms of the box model.

One answer suggested removing the text-indent tag from `<p>`  This results in a flush `<p>` and a smaller indent on `<li>`

#### HTML

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class=content>

<p>This is a paragraph. It has several sentences.  It goes on and on and on and on. It has several sentences.  It goes on and on and on and on. </p>

<ul class="c">
  <li><p>This is a list element that is long enough to wrap, I think. But it needs to be longer to check justification. It looks a lot like a paragraph.</p></li>
 <li><p>This is a list element that is long enough to wrap, I think. But it needs to be longer to check justification.</p></li>
 </ul>

<ul class="b">
  <li><p>This is a list element that is styled using ::before and outdenting the content. Where does the extra space come from? </p></li>
   <li><p>This is a list element that is long enough to wrap, I think.</p></li>
</ul>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

.content {
  width: 40rem;
  background-color: yellow;
}

p   {
  width: 15rem;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0.6rem;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 0;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  text-indent: 1rem;
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-break: break-word;
    }


ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.b li p::before {
    content: "=>";
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    left: -2.5rem;
    }
```

Comment: Well, it clearly comes from the `content: "=>";` characters width

Comment: Would setting `li>p { text-indent: 0; }` solve the real problem? (As opposed to using ::before to hide the symptom of the problem.)

Comment: You can use a negative left margin to move the "=>" and a positive right margin to re-indent the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi Can you please check it's really helpfull for you  I just Remove p
>   tag text-indent and change ul.b li p::before left position Add
>   text-indent in ul.b li p element

```
body {
    text-align: justify;
    hyphens: auto;
    margin-left: 3rem;
}  
.content {
    width: 40rem;
    background-color: yellow;
}  
p {
    width: 15rem;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0.6rem;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    padding: 0;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    text-align: justify;
    hyphens: auto;
    word-break: break-word;
    padding: 5px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 0;
}  
ul.b li p::before {
    content: "=>";
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
}  
ul.b li p {
    text-indent: -22px;
}  
.bluetable {
    background-color: #9FF;
    border: 2px solid black;
}  
td {
    margin: 14rem;
    border: 1px dashed green;
}
```

Comment: If I remove the text-indent from <p> I then get flush left paragraphs, 1 indent on the <li>